# How to deal with storage of sockets?

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on creating the messenger, so I need to store sockets somehow, I don't know how and where. Storing ip and port number in database will load the server, so it is not the soluton. Could you please suggest how can I store sockets? Here is the code of the server of my messenger:

```
client_sockets = {} # TODO database of clients/ session
client_DB = {}
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")


def listen_for_client(cs):

    while True:
        try:
            msg = cs.recv(1024).decode()
        except Exception as e:
       
            print(f"[!] Error: {e}")
            for key, value in dict(client_sockets).items():
                if value == cs:
                    del client_sockets[key]
        else:
            msg = msg.replace(separator_token, ": ") 
        messParts = msg.split('----')
        client_sockets[messParts[1]].send(msg.encode())




while True:
   
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    print(client_socket)
    
    print(f"[+] {client_address} connected.")
    so = client_socket.fileno()

    print("{} :: :: {}".format(type(so), so))
    ss = socket.fromfd( so,socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.close()
    print(ss)
  
    try:
        un = ss.recv(1024).decode()
        client_sockets[un]=ss

    except Exception as e:
       
        print(f"[!] Error: {e}")

  
    t = Thread(target=listen_for_client, args=(ss,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for key in list(client_sockets.keys()):
    client_sockets[key].close()
s.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Even that you write several sentences twice does not make it any clearer.

Comment: Watching Dave Beazleys talk on sockets and concurrency might help you: https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is that define a list or dictionary (do not save duplicates) to save client IP and port. Create a independent thread which activated every 10 seconds or any time that fits your program. Every time thread activated, save data from list to your database and clear list. You can copy it to a temp list and put a lock on it when copying to temp list, and from temp list copy to database. In this way thread will not block main list when copying to database.

Comment: ok thanks, i found processPool executor as solution